# Read a line from console in Java

Tags: java, optimization, strings

I have to read a line of strings and split it for whitespace:

```
ArrayList<HashSet<String>> setOfStrings = new ArrayList<HashSet<String>>();
while ((currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] tokens = currentLine.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        setOfStrings.add(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(tokens[i])));
        }
    }
```

i have to do this ,and for this reason i need for each tokens a new hashSet

i need to make operations on tokens like

```
[afaf] -> one hashset in first position inside the arrayList
[bafafa] -> one hashset in second position inside the arrayList
[cssss]
[dggg]
...
```

*with your solution ,to make a unique hashset for the tokens, i can't do separate operations for each tokens.*

How can I improve the split of the `currentLine` and the insertion into the `arrayList`?  As I did it, it's very slow because I first have to split and then iterate on the array of tokens.  How can I optimize this operation?

Comment: Why not a List for the tokens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the use of a `Set` for storing the tokens deliberate? That's because you can only have unique elements in the `Set`, and the output of the following code snippet will be 1, not 2:

```
System.out.println( new HashSet<>( Arrays.asList( "a a".split( " " ) ) ).size() );
```

Also, what you are doing is to store *one* token into a new `List` via `Arrays.asList()`, this is then iterated for elements to be stored into a new `HashSet`, which is finally added to `setOfStrings`. May we know what exactly are you trying to do here? I'll attempt to illustrate the output for the following:

Input:

```
a b c
d e f
```

Output:

```
setOfStrings
    new HashSet [ "a" ]
    new HashSet [ "b" ]
    new HashSet [ "c" ]
    new HashSet [ "d" ]
    new HashSet [ "e" ]
    new HashSet [ "f" ]
```

edit:

After reading your comment, I think what you're looking for is this:

```
while ((currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] tokens = currentLine.split(" ");
    setOfStrings.add(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(tokens)));
}
```

You do not have to iterate through `tokens`... Alternative suggestion relying on the utility method from the `Collections` class:

```
while ((currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    Set<String> hashSet = new HashSet<>();
    Collections.addAll( hashSet, currentLine.split( " " ) );
    setOfStrings.add(hashSet);
}
```

Do pay attention to its Javadoc: `"The behavior of this convenience method is identical to that of c.addAll(Arrays.asList(elements)), but this method is likely to run significantly faster under most implementations."` :)

Comment: i need to do this,i know that the hashset can only have unique value,i want that!,i need to insert each token in a new hashset,how i can improve this operation? you didn't answer that.

Comment: If that's the case then you should be looking at adding all your tokens from a line into a single `HashSet` instance, not to create a `HashSet` instance per token.

Comment: so for example u suggest to do this `setOfStrings.add(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(tokens)));` ?  is there a way to add the tokens without converting them into an array with this `Arrays.asList(tokens))`

Comment: please see question update.

Comment: Just to be sure we're clear on each other definitions, a line `"a a"` will yield two tokens after `split()`, and there will only be one unique value `a`, is that your understanding too?

Comment: i read always unique values. i don't read a a a a a

Comment: are there ways to improve this without using `Arrays.asList(tokens[i]))`?

Comment: If you see my alternative suggestion + the Javadoc for `Collections.addAll()` you don't have to use `Arrays.asList()` explicitly. Also, if you are sure you always read unique values, then is there still a need for using a `Set`? Your edit on your question still isn't that clear, I suggest including a sample input/output like what I've done in my answer so that everyone else can be clearer about what you're asking. :)

Comment: i want to create a new hashset for each tokens.i' m asking for the better performance to do it